# toggle with menu with Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm working for hours on this problem but I didn't find any answers.
I've got a toolbar with buttons and a menu:

```
new Ext.Toolbar({
    items: [
        {
            text: 'button1',
            toggleGroup: "draw",
            allowDepress: false,
            pressed: true,
        },
        {
            text: 'button2',
            toggleGroup: "draw",
            allowDepress: false,
            pressed: false,
        },
        {
            text: 'menu',
            enableToggle: true,
            menu: {
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'menuButton1',
                        toggleGroup: "draw",
                        allowDepress: false,
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'menuButton2',
                        toggleGroup: "draw",
                        allowDepress: false,
                    }
                ]

            }
        }
    ]
})
```

(this is just an example that's very close to my code)

The problem:
the toggling is not working. I want only one of the 4 buttons selected. Toggling with button1 and button2 is working but not with the menu buttons. Where is the problem?

Comment: I think you can't toggle menu items..

Answer (score 0):

By default menus in extjs can not be togglable,
if you still want to use menu then you can use `Ext.menu.CheckItem` and use checked property to initially render as checked item

Comment: thanks. i tried it that way. perhaps it is not very logical to make a menu togglable. i try it now with a splitbutton. that combines the button and the menu